# how to set onclicklistener on this kind of list

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

i got a slider which contain a custom listview it was working fine when i was using `android.R.layout_simple_list_item` when i changed it to my own layout it looks better but the onclick method i was using stopped working but with errors it just don't apply the clicking method can anyone tell me whats the problem in my code.
Thank?
here is my java code

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment
{
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.burger_list,R.id.textView2, new String[] { " Main menu", " My  schedual", " Location", " Media", " Tickets", "News","Facebook","Instagram","Policy","Share this app"}));
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ((ActivityMenu)getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();

    if(position==0)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMainMenu.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }      
    else if(position==1)
     {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMySchedual.class);
        startActivity(i); 
     }

    else if(position==2)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMySchedual.class);
       startActivity(i); 
    }
    else if(position==3)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMedia.class);
       startActivity(i); 
    }

}
}
```

and here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#556B2F" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrolololo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#556B2F" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_list_sep" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This class is my slider. Everything I change in my `MenuFragment` it will affect it. I am stuck!

```
public class ActivityMenu extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSlideoutHelper = new SlideoutHelper(this);
    mSlideoutHelper.activate();
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(com.korovyansk.android.slideout.R.id.slideout_placeholder, new MenuFragment(), "menu").commit();
    mSlideoutHelper.open();
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        mSlideoutHelper.close();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


public SlideoutHelper getSlideoutHelper(){
    return mSlideoutHelper;
}

private SlideoutHelper mSlideoutHelper;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that happens for you because in your layout something is stealing the focus from your click
try putting this line on the row layout you have, and all the items inside it as well, in their respective xml files

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

EDIT:

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment
{
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.burger_list,R.id.textView2, new String[] { " Main menu", " My  schedual", " Location", " Media", " Tickets", "News","Facebook","Instagram","Policy","Share this app"}));
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); //<-- remove this line, you are supposed to send //it if you don't handle the event, not if you do
    ((ActivityMenu)getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();

    if(position==0)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMainMenu.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }      
    else if(position==1)
     {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMySchedual.class);
        startActivity(i); 
     }

    else if(position==2)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMySchedual.class);
       startActivity(i); 
    }
    else if(position==3)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ActivityMedia.class);
       startActivity(i); 
    }

}
}




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" //<-- put this line here, also put it in the    XML //where your listview resides
android:background="#556B2F" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrolololo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" //<-- put this line here
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" //<-- put this line here
        android:background="#556B2F" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_list_sep" />
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>






    public class ActivityMenu extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSlideoutHelper = new SlideoutHelper(this);
    mSlideoutHelper.activate();
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(com.korovyansk.android.slideout.R.id.slideout_placeholder, new MenuFragment(), "menu").commit();
    mSlideoutHelper.open();
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        mSlideoutHelper.close();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


public SlideoutHelper getSlideoutHelper(){
    return mSlideoutHelper;
}

private SlideoutHelper mSlideoutHelper;

}
```

Comment: It did not work bro still the same iam not able to open any activity inside my list any other solutions? please

Comment: did you check if the onclick method is even called? can you put a log inside the items, above the "launching" of the activity, and see if it is even activated?
also remove the call to "super.onListItemClick" you're supposed to send that if you *DONT* handle the click, not if you do

Comment: can you show me how to do that cause iam getting no result please

Comment: i updated my question cause every solution u gave me is affecting this class too!

Comment: if i put instead of my layout android.R.Layout.simple_list_item1 it works perfectly but here now i cant put a background for my list and i cant put a separator. Can i do that in android.R.Layout.simple_list_item1 or i have to make my own layout which iam having a problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `ListView` in the XML?

From the Android docs, because you're using a `ListFragment` you can declare a `ListView` in your XML with the id `@android:id/list`. It's the canonical list identifier.

Second, assuming you have a `ListView`, where are you setting its `onItemClickListener`? You will need something like:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {...});
```

I'd do this in the `onViewCreated()` method. At this point the existence of the `ListView` is guaranteed.